# Button CSS not working fine in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: css

Hi I have 4 buttons in a row. Button CSS is coming fine in IE11,Chrome and Safari and all other browser except IE10. Here is my code
Hi I have 4 buttons in a row. Button CSS is coming fine in IE11,Chrome and Safari and all other browser except IE10. Here is my code
My HTML

{{actionBarTitle}}

```
                </div>
                <div class="action-line col-xs-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 abc">
                    <!-- Edit button -->
                    <div>
                        <button class="btn btn-large deactivate-btn-large" title="{{::'title.edit' | translate}}" ng-click="showEditUserPanel()" title="" ng-disabled="!actionButtonStatus.EDIT">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg"></i>
                            <span class="action-button-text">{{::'button.edit' | translate}}</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button class="btn btn-large deactivate-btn-large" title="{{::'title.assign.roles' | translate}}" ng-click="showAssignRolesPanel()" title="" ng-disabled="!actionButtonStatus.ASSIGN">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-secret fa-lg"></i>
                            <span class="action-button-text">{{::'button.assign' | translate}}</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="active-send-select" pull-left btn-group>
                        <button class="btn btn-large dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="{{::'title.send' | translate}}" ng-disabled="!actionButtonStatus.SENT">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
                            <span class="action-button-text">{{::'label.button.send' | translate}}</span>
                            <i class="icon-chevron-down pull-right" style="margin-top:-20px;"></i>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu filter-state dropdown" ng-show="!user.isPeUser">
                            <li><a href="" ng-click="userstatus == 'Complete'||sendActivationNotification()"><span class="{{userstatus == 'Complete'? 'resettest': ''}}">{{::'label.dropdown.sendActivation' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="" ng-click="(userstatus == 'Notified' || userstatus == 'Added') || onSendPasswordReset()"><span class="{{(userstatus == 'Notified' || userstatus == 'Added')? 'resettest': '' }}">{{::'label.dropdown.resetPassword' | translate}}</span></a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu filter-state dropdown" ng-show="user.isPeUser">
                         <li>
                                <a href="" ng-click="welcomeEmail()">{{::'label.send.welcomeEmail' | translate}}</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                    <div class="action-bar-item" >
                        <button class="btn btn-large deactivate-btn-large" ng-click="changeUserState()" title={{title}} ng-disabled="!actionButtonStatus.ENABLE">
                            <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-lg"></i>
                            <span class="action-button-text">{{getEnableButtonLabel()}}</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="panel-title">
                <span>{{panelTitle}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row inner-row full-panel" ng-include="'script/item-full-panel/user-select-panel.html'" ng-if="panelSelector.USER_SELECT"></div>
    <div class="row inner-row full-panel" ng-include="'script/item-full-panel/user-add-panel.html'" ng-if="panelSelector.USER_ADD"></div>
    <div class="row inner-row full-panel" ng-include="'script/item-full-panel/user-edit-panel.html'" ng-if="panelSelector.USER_EDIT"></div>
    <div class="row inner-row full-panel" ng-include="'script/item-full-panel/user-detail-panel.html'" ng-if="panelSelector.USER_DETAILS"></div>
    <div class="row inner-row full-panel" ng-include="'script/item-full-panel/user-import-panel.html'" ng-if="panelSelector.USER_IMPORT"></div>
    <div class="row inner-row full-panel" ng-include="'script/item-full-panel/user-state-change-panel.html'" ng-if="panelSelector.USER_STATE_CHANGE"></div>
    <div class="row inner-row full-panel" ng-include="'script/item-full-panel/password-reset-panel.html'" ng-if="panelSelector.USER_PASSWORD_RESET"></div>
    <div class="row inner-row full-panel" ng-include="'script/item-full-panel/user-activation-panel.html'" ng-if="panelSelector.USER_ACTIVATE"></div>
    <div class="row inner-row full-panel" ng-include="'script/item-full-panel/welcome-email-panel.html'" ng-if="panelSelector.USER_WELCOME_EMAIL"></div>
    <div class="row inner-row full-panel" ng-include="'script/assign-roles-panel/assign-roles-panel.html'" ng-if="panelSelector.ASSIGN_ROLES"></div>

   <!-- access denied template -->
    <div class="row inner-row full-panel" ng-if="panelSelector.ACCESS_DENIED">
        <div class="row scrowable" ge-scroll-port>
            <div class="access-denied-msg">
                Access Denied
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

    My CSS

      .deactivate-btn-large {
                    width: 90px;
                    margin-left: 10px;
                    margin-bottom: 10px;
                    height: 34px;
                    border: 1px solid @grayLight;
                    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
                    margin-right: 10px;
                }

      .action-button-text {
                    display: inline-block;
                }

     .active-send-select {
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    width: 90px;
                    button.btn {
                        width: 90px;
                        height: 34px;
                        padding: 5px 5px;
                        border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
                        margin-left: 10px;
                        text-align: left;
                        i {
                            padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
                        }
                    }
                    .dropdown {
                        margin-top: -5px;
                        margin-left: 225px;
                    }
                    .active-filter-option {
                        color: @black;
                    }
                }
     .dropdown {
                        margin-top: -5px;
                        margin-left: 225px;
                    }

[This is coming correct][1]


[In IE 10 it is coming like that][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWjN2.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO3BZ.png

Where I am doing wrong. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block` or `float: left` on the `button's parent`

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work..

Comment: Adjust the parent's width of the button's parent (div).

Comment: I used bootstap so divided in two parts here is the code      <div class="group1 col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 single-elm-style">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-lg title-action" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="back()" title="{{::'button.back' | translate}}"></i>
                    <span class="title-text">{{actionBarTitle}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="action-line col-xs-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 abc">
                    <!-- Edit button -->
                    <div> <button class="btn btn-large deactivate-btn-large

Comment: Hard to guess because your markup is not complete. Edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [prefixfree](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/), this will help you to put the right prefix for css properties that needs specific prefix for a specific borwser. Just load the js file in the `head` tag

Comment: Shouldn't recommend this method because it will add another request to the server. Use gulp workflow instead and adding the autoprefix there is much better. I already quit gulp 1 year ago and just use prepros to compile anything. I am using sass + bourbon and other preprocessor. One of my favorite advantage is prepros can transpile babel code into es5 :)